# Why overflow-y is not working as expected

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I'm trying to have a scrollbar on Y axis when text gets to the end of the right side of the div.
The problem is that when I have texts with spaces its working great but when I'm entering long text without spaces the text is overlapping to X axis.
This is how it's looks:
[image: Example of bad overflow behavior]

I'm working with styled components.

This is code samples:

```
// The container of the white box
const TodoContainer = styled.div`
  display: flex;
`;

// The white box with text inside
const TextContainer = styled.div`
  text-decoration: ${(props) => props.completed && "line-through"};
  background: #fff;
  color: ${(props) => props.theme.palette.text.primary};
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  min-width: 20rem;
  max-width: 20rem;
  height: 2rem;
`;
```

Comment: try the  `word-wrap: break-word; property to force breaking long words

Answer (score 0):

You would have to tell css to break long words into new line if needed.

Just add `word-break: break-all`.

```
const TextContainer = styled.div`
   word-break: break-all;
   ...
`;
```

**Note**: You could also use `overflow-wrap: break-word`. Thanks @trixn

Comment: It is `word-wrap: break-word;`.

Comment: Working! great. Thank you so much.

Comment: @trixn There's also [word-break](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break) property. `word-wrap` (deprecated) breaks lines in between **words**, meanwhile `word-break` breaks line in between **characters**. Also it has been renamed in css3 spec to `overflow-wrap`

Comment: @trixn Chrome console doesn't even recognize such prop `word-wrap`. Are you sure its correct?

Comment: @kinduser https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap. It definitely exists and in my opinion it is better suited as it only breaks a long word if it spans more than the available horizontal space. In case there are multiple words it will try to break at spaces whereas `word-break: break-all;` will also break small words.

Comment: @k It has been renamed to `overflow-wrap` in the current spec but `word-wrap` should work too.

Comment: @trixn `overflow-wrap`, this one exists. Wasnt even aware of such prop, thanks, will mention it.

Comment: @SamuelHulla `word-wrap` is not deprecated according to the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-3/#overflow-wrap-property). It is a valid alias to the newer `overflow-wrap` and considered legacy. But I agree that `overflow-wrap` might be a better name and should be preferred.

Comment: > *"For legacy reasons, UAs must treat word-wrap as an legacy name alias of the overflow-wrap property."*

Perhaps shouldn't have said deprecated, but yeah you catch my drift.